# Content Approval along with Target Audience does not work properly in Posts list of Blog site of SharePoint O365 portal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

After Content Approval functionality is ON in Posts list of Blog site of SharePoint O365 portal, and as soon as I entered the item its Approval Status becomes Pending. Then I made the Target Audience feature enabled in the same list, after that when I entered the item, its status becomes Approved rather than Pending.

These both features works properly in normal list.